# From where can I download Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, downloads

From where can I download Ubuntu 12.04 only. Not even 12.04.*.

I want only 12.04 LTS. I tried to download from [Ubuntu CD Images](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/), but there is only 12.04.3

Because 12.04.* and all later versions has lots of critical bugs, like:

- Wi-Fi hotspot doesn't work
- USB 3G Datacard doesn't work
- When I connects to any Wi-Fi network all other connected system on same Wi-Fi network doesn't access internet even network printer. **This is unbelievable, but its happening!**
- Startup Disk Creator doesn't work
- Empathy doesn't connect to any account properly
- and many things

> All later versions of Ubuntu are totally worst.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where I can find the status of the released versions of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/382579/where-i-can-find-the-status-of-the-released-versions-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Ubuntu 12.04 from [**here**](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the direct links to download Ubuntu 12.04 (just 12.04) 32- and 64-bit:

- [Ubuntu 12.04: PC (Intel x86) desktop CD](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.0/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso)
- [Ubuntu 12.04: 64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop CD](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.0/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso)

I got these by first navigating to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/, then clicking on `12.04.0` in the directories at the bottom. The page will say `12.04.2`, but you can scroll down and get links to everything else (12.04, 12.04.1, 12.04.2).

<sub>They really need to sort out those directories. It's like a maze!</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can download ubuntu 12.04.0 from  [here](http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu-old-releases/releases/12.04.0/)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anyone looking at this from this point out, please know that some of the md5sum hashes are incorrect on the http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu-old-releases/releases/12.04.0/ link.

For instance, if you downloaded Ubuntu Studio 12.04.0 AMD64 ISO from the UBUNTUSTUDIO directory, the installation will fail half way with an "[ERRNO 5] Input/Output Error" saying there is something wrong with your DVD or Hard Disk when there isn't. Downloading that ISO from the PRECISE directory will give you the correct Ubuntu Studio.

Look that the MD5sums at the top of those pages, and compare them to the ones found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Always check those hashes!

Answer (score 0):

I used this link for my PC Compaq Presario CQ5000 (64 bits) http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

Answer (score -1):

I found this link searching for the same version:

http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu-old-releases/releases/12.04.0/