# Where can I find the status of the released versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: release-management

I want to know where I can find updated information about all the stable and in-development versions of Ubuntu, where I can find this information?

> This question is meant to be a canonical question. It expects to answer the following questions:
>
> - Is X version stable yet?
> - Is X version in beta?
> - Is X version still supported?
> - What versions are still supported?
> - What are the versions in Beta/Alpha?
> - Until where X version will be supported?
> - Have X version ceased support?
> - When will be X version released?
> - Where I can download any release?
> - When will the next LTS version of Ubuntu be released?
>
> **The list is not exhaustive.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Supported Releases

The currently supported releases will always be in the Wiki page of Ubuntu at:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReleaseTeam#Releases.Current

This includes the current point release, Long Term Support release and regular releases.

### Future (in development) Releases

For future (beta/alpha) versions of Ubuntu you may check:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReleaseTeam#Releases.Future

### Older (EOL) Releases

To know the supported dates of older (EOL) releases, you may visit:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReleaseTeam#Releases.End_of_Life

---

All releases can be downloaded at http://releases.ubuntu.com, for older releases you may look at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com.

The release schedule of any version will be at `https://wiki.ubuntu.com/<codename>/ReleaseSchedule`, replacing `<codename>` with the codename for that release, e.g. for Trusty Tahr:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule

Answer (score 9):

Over at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases) they keep this useful graph:

[image: Click for full size.]

Comment: Through the graphic is cool but doesn't answer all the questions that were meant to answer with this canonical post.

Comment: It answered the original question, before you changed it.

Comment: Err... you sure http://askubuntu.com/revisions/382579/1

Comment: @LuísdeSousa graphic updated for the latest versions of Ubuntu