# What is the newest version of PHP/MySQL for Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: release-management

I'm just trying to make sure I am getting the right information, since I won't have access to my server for a few days. So what is the newest version of PHP/MySQL for Ubuntu 10.04?

I am currently running 5.2.3 and it looks as if 5.3.2 is the latest supported version.
I am trying to install a new version of RoundCube that required 5.3 and I need to upgrade soon.

Are there any considerations I should keep in mind before upgrading?

Thanks (and sorry for the dumb question)

Answer (score 0):

Mysql:

- `lucid` main repository has mysql version `5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1`
- `lucid-updates` has `5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1`

For PHP:

- `lucid` main repository has php version `5.3.2-1ubuntu4.21`
- `lucid-updates` has `5.3.2-1ubuntu4.21`

Anyway, you should consider installing 12.04 instead since 10.04 support cease in April 2015 (less than 5 months). To know where you can find the support dates, see [my other answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/382580/169736)