# Where can I get older versions of Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, release-management

I have an old Compaq NC6000 computer, and the newest kernels don't work.

I need to use an older version of Lubuntu.  Where can I download the older versions lf Lubuntu?

Comment: google is your friend.

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded the correct platform version? (32bit/64bit)

Comment: duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/382579/169736

Comment: Yes I downloaded it twice, and the message I get is something like this computer does not support this kernel needs some PA and it gets cut.

Comment: The links on the so-called duplicate does not have any LUbuntu downloads whatsoever, so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: This looks like it has all of the old LUbuntu releases: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/

Answer (score 3):

There are a few links listed here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/PreviousReleases

Comment: You might want to use 10.04. the first link says it might work on discontinued computer architectures.

Comment: Linked page is outdated and does not have more recent older releases, for example 19.04.