# Doubts regarding the 15.04 upgrade (is it inevitable and unavoidable?)

Tags: upgrade

I recently (on the first week of November 2014) upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10 and encountered some problems after it was all done.

Now that 2015 is just around the corner, will it be in any way mandatory to upgrade to 15.04?

Since I'm a newbie using Ubuntu (and my laptop is not the fastest machine), my questions are:

- Will I necessarily have to upgrade to 15.04?
- If 14.04 feels and works fine, do I have to keep the 14.04 .iso DVD I burned in a glass box just in case I want to reinstall because the Ubuntu download page will not offer the 14.04 in the future?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 being a Long Term Support release will be available for download until April, 2019, and you can also install it from the DVD that you burned. Apart from that, look at the Ubuntu Release Timeline graph at: [Where I can find the status of the released versions of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/382579/where-i-can-find-the-status-of-the-released-versions-of-ubuntu).

Comment: Thank you @karel.

It is a relief to know that there is a chance to get myself more used to a particular distro (14.04) and that any upgrade is on the long run.

Comment: Note that you can downgrade to 14.04 as well - it will last longer than 15.04. Note you can use a EOL release, just you won't get any updated software from the repos, and it may be really bad not having the latest security updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.10 will go [End-of-Life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) on May, 2015.  Support for the release will end, and updates will be sparse, perhaps.

On the otherhand, 14.04 is a long-term release, and will be supported and downloadable until April 2019

You can always stay on an old release, and possibly suffer from security issues or lack of updates, or you can go with Ubuntu 15 (which will be short term, only 6 to 12 months of support), or revert at some point to 14.04

Comment: Thank you @Charles Green.

It is a relief to know that there is a chance to get myself more used to a particular distro (14.04) and that any upgrade is on the long run.

Comment: Eh - you never know what's going to happen.  I'm running 14.10 now, and I find it to be "gooder" than 14.04, although I also switched to Ubuntu-Gnome and feel that it is more responsive on my system.  Ubuntu people seem to fall into two camps:  Never upgrade until absolutely required, and update to the bleeding edge as soon as it's available....