# When will Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 be released?

Tags: gnome

Please tell the date of release for the stable version of the GNOME flavor.

Comment: [April 21st](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule)?

Comment: Dammit. Meant http://askubuntu.com/questions/382579/where-i-can-find-the-status-of-the-released-versions-of-ubuntu

Comment: @incBrain Your comment was more useful than any of the answers posted.

Answer (score 1):

21st April 2016 will be release date of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus).It was to be expected for Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS to ship with GNOME 3.20.

Comment: You got a source for that? I've been looking myself but their blog has been very quiet since the Wiley release?

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/10/ubuntu-16-04-release-schedule-release-schedule-date-xenial-xerus  here look at the release shedule and also look the pic http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/xerus-release-date.jpg .There you can see the gnome logo (in pic).

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, I've been looking for confirmation that 16.04 will indeed ship with GNOME 3.20 - as I believe previous releases shipped a version behind the main GNOME release, have you got a source where devs have confirmed we're getting 3.20? (If so... awesome)

Comment: I cant remember the link.But I have seen it somewhere.Though I am also not sure about that.Should wait for 2 months.

Comment: Got a link http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-gnome-16-04-lts-gets-first-gnome-3-19-packages-for-daily-build-496640.shtml

Comment: Ace link, thanks for that - looks like they're still using [google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+UbuntuGNOMEorg/posts/Am1aL2CA3R7)! Sadly looks like we're getting Gnome 3.19 and not 3.20... :( Alas, may have to push the upgrade myself and see what breaks. Thanks for going back and sourcing links.

Comment: perhaps I'm off my rocker anyway - turns out gnome 3.20 isn't due for release until [March 16](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GNOME-3.20-Release-Schedule)... so perhaps slightly optimistic to expect the team to turn that around in a month...