# Does installing kernel 4.13 on Ubuntu 12.04 change the update policy?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, kernel, updates

I know that Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is no longer getting app updates and security updates.

If I update the kernel to the latest 4.13 ATM. Does that change the update policy or is it strictly based on the OS version and not the kernel?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 has been EOL for quite some time.  You need to install a supported version.  You may still be able to "upgrade" to 14.04, but if you're going to install fresh, I'd recommend 16.04.

Comment: Reviewers: I *really* don't think this is off-topic. It is true that this question includes a hypothetical involving performing an action on an EoL system, but the purpose of this hypothetical is to ask what is and is not still updated and supported. This question is asking about the existing *policy* for updates (and thus even applies to other releases, including to the *plans* users must make for the future of their currently supported releases).

Comment: well i'm running 14.04 with the 4.13 kernel trying to run ubuntu in lighter form but having all the updates possible with the least amount of resources. but i wanted to see if it was possible to do a workaround with 12.04 like with windows xp extending the security updates till 2019 tricking your system into thinking its running windows server 2003. But i do know that it was last april that ubuntu 12.04 reached it's EoL, so it's not that out of date

Comment: No, because you're fetching from repositories. The repositories for 12.04 is simply not updated any more - and switching to newer repositories would simply give you the new version. There's no reason not to upgrade. If you desire light weight, have a look at for instance xfce.

Comment: I agree the question is on-topic and useful, but in terms of your real problem, using 12.04 for lightness is not a good approach. Use a lighter DE like Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead. Package management on Ubuntu (as on other distros) relies on maintained repositories, so it's impractical and unsafe to use an unsupported version.

Answer (score 11):

The policy is based on the OS version and not on the kernel version.

- [What versions of Ubuntu are supported by Canonical and what is an end of life version?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14991/544264)
- [Where can I find the status of the released versions of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382579/where-can-i-find-the-status-of-the-released-versions-of-ubuntu)
- [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/110477/544264)