# How do I download old Ubuntu versions?

Tags: downloads, versions

I want to create VMs of old versions of Ubuntu, such as 10.10, 8.04, 4.10 and more. But how do I download old versions of Ubuntu? My main idea is [The Wayback Machine](https://archive.org). But is there anything more easier than that?

Comment: As mentioned by Terrance [this](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) website contains all the old Ubuntu releases. Just select the version you want from the list, click on it and select the ISO that matches your system (e.g. `*-amd64.iso` for an AMD-based system) . Good luck!

Comment: Note that the Wayback Machine does not always provide specific versions of content, and often does not archive large files. In this particular case, I spot-checked several versions dating back to 2010, and in every case the final link to download an ISO resulted in an error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find the status of the released versions of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382579/where-can-i-find-the-status-of-the-released-versions-of-ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find the source code of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167468/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 27):

You can download all the old releases from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is useful indeed. But sometimes you also want to be able to download individual `.deb` files for an old release. Are they permanently deleted from the web once the release is no longer supported or can they be downloaded somewhere?

Comment: @PerLundberg I actually don't think they keep them all.  I do know that the `.deb` packages are stored on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu and you can try looking there.  I do know that if you install an unsupported or old release setting the repos like in https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release will allow you to upgrade the packages to the newest versions before that distro version went EOL.

Comment: Thanks, that was useful info!

Answer (score 0):

if you want older version (.iso file) of ubuntu or any other linux distros:

https://soft.lafibre.info/