# Finding Precise Pangolin (12.04) repository

Tags: 12.04, repository, disk-image

Where can I find a repository for Precise Pangolin (12.04LTS)?

I am not asking a question about this specific version of Ubuntu. I just want to know where I can download it, If it's still available.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Why are you looking for looking for almost 12 year old version? It has reached the end of its life and is not maintained anymore.

Comment: End of life release is dead and end of life.  You **SHOULD NOT** be using 12.04 anymore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I download old Ubuntu versions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1227763/)

Answer (score 1):

The url for EOL repositories is https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/

The direct link for Precise Pangolin (12.04.5 LTS) is: https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/

This Ununtu comunity page describes how to update from old-releases: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades